# Cannot use python3 in Spark cluster after modifying spark-env.sh

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

For some extremely annoying reason, the spark-ec2 files (Im using Spark 1.5) spin up a cluster that uses python2.6 (!!!) by default, so I cannot use dictionary comprehensions.

I set `export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3"` in my spark-env.sh file (the one in the spun up cluster) but I still get the error:

```
java.io.IOException (Cannot run program "/usr/bin/python3": error=2, No such file or directory)
```

1. How can I effectively change the version of python?
2. Better yet, how can I spin up a cluster that uses python3 as default?

I'm surprised to see the default python is 2.6, not even 2.7... I'm sure there has to be good reasons for this...

Comment: The error appears to be that spark can't find `/usr/bin/python3`, are you sure it is available on your spark cluster? Also, does the spark process (likely run by a different user) have access to this file? The default isn't set to be python 2.6 or 2.7, the default is simply your cluster's default python

Comment: @Snoozer yes I seem to have a path problem. I'm positive its available in the cluster. I tried with python27 and now things are running until I use pandas, in which case it shows `ImportError: ('No module named numpy', <function subimport at 0x7f1a5bd65488>, ('numpy',))` However: `$ ls /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/` shows `numpy  numpy-1.10.1.egg-info  pandas  pandas-0.17.0.egg-info`. I've installed pandas and numpy for both python34 and python27, I can import the modules if I run the appropriate version of python, but the spark-submit job isn't able to find it.

Comment: Try adding `/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages` to the spark worker's `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, to make sure they can see all the packages

Comment: @Snoozer I tried that and it's not working. Do I need to propagate somehow the newly installed python modules to the workers? Something akin to copy-dir but for the python libraries?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean. If you've installed new modules you do need to install them on the machines the workers are running. You can also do some hacky "print debugging" by creating a trivial rdd then:
`rdd = sc.parallelize([1])`
`rdd.map(lambda x: sys.subprocess('ls /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/').collect()`
`rdd.map(lambda x: sys.subprocess('echo $PYTHONPATH').collect()`

To make sure that those packages are indeed installed on the worker machines and the environment variable is what you think it is.

Comment: Do you mean subprocess.call? sys has no subprocess function.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course, just something to inspect what those variables actually are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://spark-project.atlassian.net/browse/SPARK-922

I need to type 30 characters or more